# JPA query creation order by

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to learn Spring on my own, and I'm planning to do that by creating a blog web app. I already have the basic blog functionality working, which is a page to display blog posts, and a page with a form to submit one. The page to display the blog posts shows the latest blog post, and a list of the titles of all the blog posts in the db.

To get an ordered list of blog posts out of the database I first created an sql query inside my Repository interface. This works, but now I want to use the functionality where I can just type the method name in the interface, instead of hardcoded sql. I found the supported keywords here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation , and tried to implement it.

So with my method `findAllOrderByIdDesc()` I'm trying to achieve the same thing as with my sql query. I'm not sure why it doesn't work, I think I used the keywords correctly?

The stackstrace (which I don't fully understand):
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property desc found for type int
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:330)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:271)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:188)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:277)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:257)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:71)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:57)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:90)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
        ... 32 more

My repository interface:

```
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Integer> {

@Query("select p from Post p order by p.id desc")
Iterable<Post> findLastFirst();

Iterable<Post> findAllOrderByIdDesc();

}
```

My Post entity:

```
@Entity
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private Date date;
private String title;
@Lob
private String body;

protected Post() {
    date = new Date();
}

public Post(String title, String body) {
    this.date = new Date();
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

Comment: id should be type Long, not int.

Comment: Using a long instead of int gives the same result. Earlier I also tried to sort on Date instead, which also gave the same error.

Comment: did you used long or Long? Long should be mappable.

Comment: I'm missing a @Temporal annotation on that date property. And its not a good idea to call the property 'date' since that may just be a reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: @wxyz id can be primitive or wrapper of primitives.

Comment: @wxyz I have used Long.

Comment: @Gimby Thank you for those remarks! (I'm still quite new on the JPA front aswel)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an extension to CrudRepository called [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html)

```
 public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Integer> {}
```

Then just call .findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id")); instead of findAllOrderByIdDesc();

Comment: Thanks for that! Like this solution more then sql in my code :D

Answer (score 166):

I know it's a bit late but this may help others.

Just put `BY` before `ORDER`, like this: `findAllByOrderByIdDesc`

It should work.

Comment: Its not working for CrudRepository do we need extend any other class?

Comment: It should work. Maybe you can open a new question showing some code, frameworks versions and configurations.

Comment: can you please explain why? am I right assuming this is a bug?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Had the same problem, i was missing the By before the Order.
Thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: It is not late at all. This should be clear in the documentation by now.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! I think you need to have PagingAndSortingRepository or JpaRepository in order to sort (e.g. not CrudRepository).

Comment: Cool fix! Works as expected! Thanks @PauloPedroso

Comment: It works because it's designed this way. Although the semantics doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm a little late to the game but..

Another fix would be to correct the syntax on your named query in your repository.

You have: `Iterable<Post> findAllOrderByIdDesc();`

When it should be: `Page<Post> findAllByOrderByIdDesc();`

Note the addition of the `By` keyword after `findAll`. This marks the beginning of your filtering statements.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is stupid but did you try just `"from Post order by id desc"` instead of `"select p from Post p order by p.id desc"`

Comment: Your suggestion works, but I'm trying to create a solution without sql. (if possible)