# Spring boot query failing with MSSQL database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application version 1.4.3.RELEASE
that is working with MS SQL db using driver version 4.1

i tried to implement a query to bring the top 100 results in the following way

```
public interface EventTrackingService extends CrudRepository<EventTracking, Integer> {

    public List<EventTracking> findBySwitchIpOrderByTimestampDesc(String switchIp);

    public List<EventTracking> findTop100ByOrderByTimestampDesc();  

}
```

project compiles nicely but when i hit the second query **findTop100ByOrderByTimestampDesc** i get the following error:

> Hibernate: 
>       /* select
>           generatedAlias0 
>       from
>           EventTracking as generatedAlias0 
>       order by
>           generatedAlias0.timestamp desc */ select
>               TOP ?  eventtrack0_.nEventNumber as nEventNu1_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.strAction as strActio2_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.strEventMsg as strEvent3_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.strEventType as strEvent4_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.FHandleEvent as FHandleE5_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.StrIpAddress as StrIpAdd6_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.strMACAddress as strMACAd7_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.nPort as nPort8_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.strSwitchIP as strSwitc9_9_,
>               eventtrack0_.nDate as nDate10_9_ 
>           from
>               SWAT.dbo.tblEventsTracking eventtrack0_ 
>           order by
>               eventtrack0_.nDate desc 2017-04-20 03:38:28.791 DEBUG 11016 --- [-nio-555-exec-3] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  :
>   SQLServerPreparedStatement:3 created by (ConnectionID:10
>   ClientConnectionId: a144ec47-037d-40a7-be92-db1725614208) 2017-04-20
>   03:38:28.807 DEBUG 11016 --- [-nio-555-exec-3]
>   c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  :
>   SQLServerPreparedStatement:3: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0,
>   SQL:/* select generatedAlias0 from EventTracking as generatedAlias0
>   order by generatedAlias0.timestamp desc */ select TOP @P0 
>   eventtrack0_.nEventNumber as nEventNu1_9_, eventtrack0_.strAction as
>   strActio2_9_, eventtrack0_.strEventMsg as strEvent3_9_,
>   eventtrack0_.strEventType as strEvent4_9_, eventtrack0_.FHandleEvent
>   as FHandleE5_9_, eventtrack0_.StrIpAddress as StrIpAdd6_9_,
>   eventtrack0_.strMACAddress as strMACAd7_9_, eventtrack0_.nPort as
>   nPort8_9_, eventtrack0_.strSwitchIP as strSwitc9_9_,
>   eventtrack0_.nDate as nDate10_9_ from SWAT.dbo.tblEventsTracking
>   eventtrack0_ order by eventtrack0_.nDate desc         2017-04-20
>   03:38:28.815 DEBUG 11016 --- [-nio-555-exec-3]
>   c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerException  : *** SQLException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   '@P0'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
>   2017-04-20 03:38:28.815  WARN 11016 --- [-nio-555-exec-3]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 102, SQLState:
>   S0001 2017-04-20 03:38:28.815 ERROR 11016 --- [-nio-555-exec-3]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax near
>   '@P0'.

Is this a JPA bug with the database or my query is wrong

i've used reference from here
https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/15/whats-new-in-spring-data-evans#user-content-statically-limiting-results

Comment: Please also post your `EventTracking` class.

Comment: In my opinion you do not need that first 'By' as there are no query params. So just try findTop100OrderByTimestampDesc

Comment: without the first By the project cant compile, found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374437/jpa-query-creation-order-by

Answer (score 0):

The `First` and `Top` keywords don't play well with some SQL implementations, and if I recall correctly, they don't work with MySQL. I always run into problems with this so I just avoid them at this point. The easiest option is to use a `Pageable` with your request and limit it that way.

So this:

`public List<EventTracking> findTop100ByOrderByTimestampDesc();`

would become this:

`public List<EventTracking> findAllByOrderByTimestampDesc(Pageable pageable);`

and you would build the parameter object like this:

`Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 100);`

Not as clean as using `Top` or `First`, but a quick fix to bypass the SQL compatibility issues that's faster than putting an entire result set into an array and taking out the first "n" of them...

Edit:

Also, check your Spring Data JPA version, it needs to be 1.7 or higher. If that doesn't work, it's the DB compatibility.